# customizing gtk window title bar

Tags: gtk

How can i customize gtk window title bar. I need to add custom buttons, and title bar image.[image]

Comment: Inevitable question... Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The title bar is drawn by the window manager, not by GTK. You can tell the window manager to set the title using `window.set_title()`, and you can set an icon, which may or may not be displayed by the window manager, using `window.set_icon()`, `window.set_icon_name()`, or `window.set_icon_from_file()`. That's about it.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Now, i will set_decorated as FALSE on window property. And add a vBox object, where i will add few hBox objects. Among them, can i add all buttons(for setting window close, minimize and maximize) and an image as title bar image. If so, how should i carry out. FYI, i am editing my question to depict how my title bar should look like.

Comment: @iSight, how will you move your window around the screen if you do that? Better to include a toolbar with your extra buttons below the title bar.

Comment: Can't i notify an event on that title bar area that i created after the removing DECORATED.

Comment: What about `set_titlebar`?

Comment: That didn't exist in 2010 when I wrote the answer, but I encourage you to add another answer explaining how to do that!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from GTK 3.10 you can use [gtk_window_set_titlebar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-titlebar)

`gtk_window_set_titlebar (GtkWindow *window, GtkWidget *titlebar)` as you can see the only arguments you need are the window that you want to customise and the *GtkWidget* that will serve as the titlebar. GTK developers suggest to use [GtkHeaderBar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html) as it provides some features that you would expect from the titlebar like close window buttons out of the box but you are free to use any other *GtkWidget*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "UV with Y variable");
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```